# iPhone - Resizing an UIImage in less than a second on an iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, optimization, graphics, resize, uiimage

I have a 5MP image coming from the back camera. I want to downsize it to put it into an ImageView without having to wait too long (it take a logn time to the UIImageView to display a 5 MP picture). So I tried many methods to resize / resample the image to make it fit a just-screen resolution (retina one). But it take around 1 sec to downsize the image.

Would you know any optimised way to be able to resize this 5MP image to the retina 960 x 640 resolution as fast as possible, and at least at less that 0.7 sec on an iPhone 4 ?

Comment: @Jesse Naugher : I'm not at home for now and don't have the code. And by the wya I didn't kept my 10th tries. I'll post my last tries when back home if this can help. But if one knows a method that works resizing the image in less that 0.7 sec, it's sure it's not one that I could have tried  :-)

Comment: @XJones : don't worry about that :-)  I'm used to accept answers and upvote those who helped or gave usefull informations. I'm just still testing them to accept the best one.

Comment: I'm not too worried about it, just kind of enjoying helping out. Good luck w/ your app.

Answer (score 6):

This is my favorite blog post and code to resize images. I haven't benchmarked it but I know of no faster way.

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying an image in an UIImageView. I understand you want a version that is equal to the size of the screen. The way I would do it: display the original image in the UIImageView directly, this shouldn't take any noticeable amount of time.

Then in a background thread resize the same image down to the size you want and update the UIImageView as soon as that is done.

This gives you something on screen immediately while you generate an optimized version at the same time.

I don't know if you are using the original image for something else, but if you really only want the screen sized image it might be an idea to use an AVCaptureSession with a preset of AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh (see `AVCaptureSession sessionPreset`). This setting results in a more reasonably sized image, which might better suit your needs.

Comment: it takes around 1-2 seconds to display the image in the ImageView. It's worse than resizing it. I'll try the `AVCaptureSession sessionPreset`that could be a great middle solution.

Comment: Ok, should have tested direct display in a UIImageView. Sorry about that.

I don't know if you're using UIImagePickerController, AVCaptureSession will act as a replacement, but you'll have to display the camera preview yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384563/show-camera-stream-while-avcapturesessions-running/3384605#3384605 on how to do this.